# боковой всплывающий popup на css

Tags: html, css, popup, popupmenu

Пытаюсь сделать всплывающий popup (на css), как на картинке (картинка в вопросе). Но безрезультатно. Сейчас deadline :( Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618C;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

        <div class="main_menu">
            <div class="main_menu_content">
                <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int"></div>Интернет
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Дополнительные услуги</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка соединения</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv"></div>Телевидение
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_video"></div>Видеонаблюдение,<br>домофон
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tvr"></div>ТВ Реклама
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_intb"></div>Интернет для бизнеса
                        </a></li>
                    <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_block">
                        <li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_account"></div>Личный кабинет
                        </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: какое окно ? выпадающий список может быть ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов на чистом css: делаем блок меню position:absolute; left:-200px; т.е. передвигаем его за рамки экрана, при наведении :hover меняем значение на left: 0px, выводя его на экран по левому краю, можно добавть свойство transition чтобы был эффект "всплывания".

Comment: можете привести пример?

Comment: Может быть вот это сойдёт за пример, хотя тут не hover, а js:  https://jsfiddle.net/fLrya9k5/

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .sideBlock{
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        left:-180px;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background:#ddd;
        color:#444;
        transition:.1s;
    }
    .sideBlock:hover{
        left:0px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="sideBlock">
    <p>Это мой контент!</p>
</div>
```